# How to upload a picture to a post from mobile?

Tags: support, mobile-web

I know about those icons used for uploading images. But those icons are not shown on mobile.

What is the other way out?

I am using Chrome. I am not using any Stack Exchange app.

On a tablet, these icons are shown, but not on the mobile. The tablet also has Chrome.

Comment: On the tablet you probably get the full site theme, on mobile device you get the mobile theme which simply does not have those icons